# Finding correlations for certain functions

Tags: differential-equations, time-series, correlation

I want to find correlations for a function $x(t)$ between pairs of times $t_1$ and $t_2$ i.e. to possibly get a functional form or fit for $\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle$. This function $x(t)$ is obtained after mapping a solution from `NDSolve`. I know how to find correlations for a discrete list or time series data but not sure how to do this for a continuous function. I can save this as a list evaluated for different time steps and then evaluate the correlators, is this the best way to do this?

EDIT: MWE and more detail

```
sol = NDSolve[{a'[t] == -I*a[t], a[0] == (1. + I)/Sqrt[2]},a, {t,0,50}];
asol[t_] := a[t] /. sol[[1]]
x[t_]:=Re@asol[t]
```

This gives a function for $x(t)$. I want to get the data for $\langle x(t_1)x(t_2)\rangle$, which in this case (since $x$ is not a random variable) will be just $x(t_1)x(t_2)$. I also want to get a functional form (using some fit) either as $f(t_1,t_2)=x(t_1)x(t_2)$ or as $f(t_1-t_2)=x(t_1)x(t_2)$ when some such (time translation) symmetry exists. One way to do this is to use `Table` with some appropriate $t$ values. I want to know if there is a way to do this using one of the built in correlation functions? and if they are more efficient than the `Table` method.

Comment: This seems more like a math problem, rather than a Mathematica language problem

Comment: I understand what correlation means mathematically. Here I'm asking about how to do this in Mathematica, specifically for a solution of `NDSolve`

Comment: "but not sure how to do this for a continuous function" With this you say that you don't know how to calculate the correlation. Also, did you even give it a shot? Do you have some minimal example in Mathematica that fails?

Comment: If  f is an random function, then ⟨x(t1)x(t2)⟩ makes sense. However if x is an ordinary function, then the expectation value is simply: x(t1) x(t2)

Comment: @HansOlo I have added a MWE now and a little more detail about what I want, thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @DanielHuber yes that is correct. I have edited the question to make that clear, thanks!

Comment: Why you do not simply define: f[x1_,x2_]= x[x1] x[x2]

Comment: @DanielHuber yes I can do that, I was just hoping to see if there is another way using a built in function like `Correlation` or `ListCorrelate` (which would also allow me to save the output of `NDSolve` separately as a time series data file). I suppose what you suggest is the easiest way, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean 'Convolution' instead of 'Correlation' ?

`Convolve` works only with analytical funtions, not interpolating functions.
Use definition for convolution:

"The convolution (f* g)  (y) of two functions f(x) and g(x) is given by  Integrate[f[x] g[y-x],{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]"

Define it with `Nintegrate` .

```
asol = a /. 
   First@NDSolve[{a'[t] == -I*a[t], a[0] == (1 + I)/Sqrt[2]}, 
     a, {t, 0, 50}];

x[t_?NumericQ] := Re[asol[t]]

nint[t2_] := 
 NIntegrate[x[t1] x[t2 - t1], {t1, -10, 10}, 
  Method -> {Automatic, "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}]

Plot[nint[t2], {t2, 10, 40}, 
 GridLines -> {{10 + 2 Pi, 10 + 4 Pi}, Automatic}]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I did mean correlaion but this is helpful, I didn't think of using convolution. I don't know if I should accept the answer though since it does not exactly answer what I asked.

Comment: @pixis   No need for accept, if not what you wanted. Wait for other answers.

Comment: @JimB , thanks, but NMinValue gave the wrong minima (and maxima), With all x[i] ranging from -7 to 7, Solve is very slow.